# Como quitar espacios en blanco (LIGHTBOX - Bootstrap)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, bootstrap

estaba probando lightbox y me encuentro con un problema, es que me aparece un espacio en blanco debajo de imagen (entre mas grande la imagen mas grande el espacio en blanco.)

index.html:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['url_img']; ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['url_img']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 480px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 20px;"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).ekkoLightbox();
        });
</script>
```

Foto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Le estás aplicando un `margin-bottom: 20px` a tu imagen, eso le da un espacio en blanco debajo, probaste quitando ese atributo?

Answer (score -1):

Revisa en tu Archivo CSS de bootstrap (css/main) lo siguiente:

> class="img-thumbnail"

Ve las opciones, debe tener la opcion **"background:"** o **"background-color:"** y en ella coloca el color que deseas, para ver los colores en html te dejare el siguiente [Link!](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/es/)

Si no te sirve la respuesta de arriba, prueba en tu css buscando el apartado:

> body{ background-color: white; }

y cambialo con los colores que aparecen en este [Link!](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/es/)